# MVVM: Does the state of the model belong in the model or the viewmodel?

Tags: mvvm

I am building an application that will be based on MVVM.
I have resolved most of my design issues, but I am left with a conceptually crucial one:
Should my ViewModel or my Model contain the state of what ever the Model models?

Initially I thought that the Model should contain its own state, but it turns out that there is a lot of boilerplate involved when passing the state to the ViewModel (which has 90% of the Model's state).

Then I though about move the entire state from the Model to the ViewModel, but this doesn't sit quite right with me, as I conceptually perceive the ViewModel as having the state of the View more than the state of the Model.

What is most accepted place to put the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct perceiving the ViewModel having the state of the view. Conceptually, the state of the model is part of the model, but it may varies depends on your specific scenario. Think of the Model as data: as something that can be serialized, can come from the server and/or can/should be persisted in a database.

If for example you have a shopping cart, then the items of the shipping cart is obviously part of the model. However, the state in the check-out process (payment method received, payment method verified, user confirmed) can go either way.

As for the boilerplate - the paradigm that works well for me with reasonable amount of boiler plate is containing (actually, referencing in c#) the entire Model within the ViewModel, and exposing getters and setters for all properties in the Model, with the appropriate even notification. e.g.

```
class PersonModel {
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private PersonModel model;
    // next 4 lines can be factored out to a BaseViewModel class
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private raise(string propName) {
        this.PropertyChanged( new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName) );
    }

    // ... repeat for each property in the model
    public string firstName {
        get { return model.fistName; }
        set { model.firstName = value; raise('firstName'); }
    }
    public string lastName {
        get { return model.lastName; }
        set { model.lastName = value; raise('lastName'); }
    }
}
```